# Case Insensitive WFS Attribute Search with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, wfs, filter

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1 to host WMS and WFS services.

I have a map (.mxd file) with a layer whose attribute table includes fields with mixed-case string data. When I open this map in ArcMap and perform a Find (Edit -> Find), selecting the appropriate layer and field, I get all matching results back, no matter what case I use in entering the search criteria. Searching for 'fireside', 'Fireside', and 'FIRESIDE' in STR_NAME all return features whose STR_NAME is 'Fireside Ln'.

However, if I take the same map and publish it to WFS in ArcCatalog, when I perform a WFS request against it, I only get matching results when searching for 'Fireside' (not 'fireside' or 'FIRESIDE').

I am performing a WFS request in the form of an XML POST. This is an example request that returns no results:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="1000" resultType='results' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
 <wfs:Query srsName="EPSG:4326" typeName="centerlines:street_centerline">
  <ogc:PropertyName>STR_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:PropertyName>TYPE</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:PropertyName>Shape</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Filter>
   <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">
   <ogc:PropertyName>STR_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>*fireside*</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
  </ogc:Filter>
 </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

I have also tried adding a matchCase="false" attribute to the ogc:PropertyIsLike tag (based on [a discussion I found on osgeo.org](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/case-insensitive-search-td6113068.html)), but this also returned no results.

Is there any way to perform a case-insensitive attribute search against a WFS service hosted on ArcGIS Server, either through modifying the request, or by performing some kind of configuration of the layer, map, or service on the server end?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to make a case insensitive search in WFS requests. The best way to do this is to normalize your database and then use some code on the client side to apply the same normalization.

Comment: "Normalize" typically refers to formal transformations of DB schemata into normal forms.  I suspect you don't mean that, but are you seriously recommending that all case distinctions in the actual *data* be obliterated?

Comment: I mean that you should create a column called lwr_name and set that to contain the lower case form of the name. Then you can apply toLower() or what ever to the user supplied string.

Comment: If you do it any other way you have thrown away your indexing